# wrote editing feature that won't work, very confused what action should in my form

Tags: python, django

Hello I wrote the code users to be able to edit the post when they want to. I could've done it successfully with delete, but for edit when the user clicks finalize edit button at the end, it won;t be edited.I have, `http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/hello/` for hello post. Now for edit page `http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/edit/hello/` .And lastly when user clicks finalize edit it should take me back to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/hello/` with edited version. However it doesn't get edited.

views.py

```
class PostUpdateView(UpdateView):
     model = Post
     form_class = PostForm
     template_name = 'main/edit.html'

     def form_valid(self, form):
            self.object = form.save(commit=False)
            # Any manual settings go here
            self.object.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.object.get_absolute_url())

     @method_decorator(login_required)
     def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        post = Post.objects.get(slug=kwargs['slug'])
        if post.moderator == request.user:
            return super(PostUpdateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return http.HttpForbidden()
```

urls.py

```
        url(r'^post/edit/(?P<slug>[\w|\-]+)/$', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-edit'),
```

for edit.html

```
<form id="post_form" method="post" action="/post/{{ post.slug }}/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form needs to submit to the edit page, so that the data can be processed and saved.